# aapt finished with non zero exit value 127

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

### here is my environment:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64
2. Android Studio 2.2
3. Android SDK build-tools 23.0.3

### here is my question:

Gradle build failed and says that

> aapt finished with non zero exit value 127

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide anything more than just that last error message? Surely the compiler said more than that...

Comment: @mike510a I had found the problem that I was running SDK-32bit on Ubuntu-64bit, just install some dependencies searched from Google will solve it. thx ~_~

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had found the problem that I was running SDK-32bit on Ubuntu-64bit, just install some dependencies searched from Google will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the necessary dependencies for this to work on: [this post](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6761/#issuecomment-209055165)

Basically, is executing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install -y lib32ncurses5 lib32gomp1 lib32z1-dev
```